# ¿Como organizar el store de Redux de un Sidebar?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Como se podrían gestionar los estados de un Sidebar en el store de Redux cuando esta activo, se abre o se cierra, deja de estar enfocado, etc...

[image: Sidebar]

Comment: Buenas, esta pregunta es muy ambigua, y es basada en opiniones, te sugiero que te pases por el centro de ayuda o como preguntar, aparte de eso creo que simplemente puedes usar un `selected: string`, o `selected:number`, es que no se como tienes el codigo tampoco :(, https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Habitualmente yo organizo el store en función del estado para que sea el componente el que se pinte de una forma u otra. Algo cómo:

```
ui_sidebar: {
expand: 1,
active: 1
...
}
```

De esta forma, el componente sabrá que ítem ha de expandir y cual enlace marcar como activo

Comment: Muchas gracias, me dio mas claridad.